# Ajax calling PHP and getting Return value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, smarty

Not used Javascript -> Ajax -> PHP -> Javascript before and I am struggling to pick-up the return value.  Ajax is calling the PHP, but all I am getting back is the HTML for the web page. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**Javascript: -**

```
onChange: function(value, text, $selectedItem) {
    jQuery.ajax({ url : 'index.php', type : 'post', data : { action: 'getTest', param : text },
                    success: function(result){
                      console.log('Sucess',result);
                    },
                      failure: function(result){ console.log('Failed'); }
                    });
}
```

**PHP: -**

```
$_action = isset($_Post['action']) ? $_Post['action'] : '0';
if ($_action == 'getTest') {
  $test = $_Post['param'];
  echo $test;
  exit;
}
```

As I said, RESULT just seems to contain the page's HTML and not the expected string value.

Thanks

Comment: You've to flush the buffer before echoing the result value in PHP, otherwise everything on that page is included in the result.

Comment: I think you need to change all occurrences of`$_Post` to `$_POST` on the PHP side, then you could perhaps set the `dataType` in the ajax options to `text` like so: `jQuery.ajax({ url : 'index.php', type : 'post', data : { action: 'getTest', param : text }, dataType: 'text'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post variable is with small caps letters. However the Variable should be full caps (`$_POST`). So your php is not going into the if statement.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

To debug these kind of issues start logging variables like `$_action` and check if their value is what you expect it to be. Then check if the if statement actually fires, etc. until you find the error.